# Unable to upload file as FormData to ASP.net from Angular

Tags: asp.net, angular, lambda

I am trying to upload a file from my angular code to an ASP.net backend.

My Angular code sends the object using FormData:

```
public uploadFiles(files) {
  console.log(files);
  if(files.length < 1) return;

  const formData = new FormData();

  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file);
    formData.append(file.name, file);
  })


  this._http.postFile('/order-processing/import-orders','application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ,formData).pipe(finalize(() => {
     console.log("Finalized");
  })).subscribe((val: any) => {
      console.log('ORDER SUBMITTED', val);     
  }, error => {
     console.log(error);            
  });
}
```

With the post file method looking like:

```
public postFile(path: string, contentType:string, body: FormData) : Observable<any> {

let headers = {
  'Content-Type': contentType,
  'Authorization': this.authToken
}
return this._http.post(environment.API_URL + path, body, {
  headers
});
```

}

My ASP.net endpoint looks like:

```
    [HttpPost, Route("hospitality/order-processing/import-orders")]
    [RequestSizeLimit(2147483648)]
    [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public IActionResult UploadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            //var req = Request.Form.Files;
            var file = Request.Form.Files;
            string folderName = "Uploads";
            string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            string newPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, folderName);
            if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
            }

            return Json("Upload Successful.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json("Failed:" + e);
        }
    }
```

If I check the network tab on my browser when I send the file, it says that my object is in the call, great, but for some reason it doesn't get picked up on the backend and when I step through the code it is not there.

I get different errors when I modify this code slightly. The error for the code in the state it is in now is "Form key or value length limit 2048 exceeded", however sometimes I get array out of bounds errors, or content boundary limit exceeded errors, it's enough to make you want to slam you face into your keyboard continually.

The whole point of this is to be able to upload an excel file to ASP.net code running in an AWS lambda, which then inserts rows in a RDS database. Am I going about this the right way? Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do? If not then what is wrong with my code that doesn't allow me to upload a file to a Web API?!

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any clues by using the error handling method? shown at https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling

Comment: @rickz I have the error catch set up in the response, but since the backend returns the error message as valid JSON, so the angular console logs the code as if it was successful. Although from this response I get the error messages that are little to no help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to set the limit of the request but the message states that the problem is with form key or value length.

Try setting the RequestFormLimits and check if that helps.

```
[HttpPost, Route("hospitality/order-processing/import-orders")]
[RequestFormLimits(KeyLengthLimit = 8192, ValueLengthLimit = 8192)]
public IActionResult UploadFile()
```